popen/Process() Laravel Function not working after switching to HTTPS in IIS
In the front (VUE), users can specify a text editor in the UI to edit/view specific files. When a button is clicked e.g. 'Edit' Button, the backend will retrieve the editor from the database and will open the specific file using that editor. The issue is it was working in local environment and also HTTP in ISS, however, switching to HTTPS no longer opens the editor with the text file although the exec/Process command returns successful response.
Here is the sample code using popen function inside an artisan command:
        $filepath = $this->argument('filepath');
        $editor = $this->argument('editor');


        // Define the command to start the editor with the temporary file
        $command = "start \"\" \"$editor\" \"$filePath\"";

        // Open the process
        $process = popen($command, 'r');

        if (is_resource($process)) {
            fclose($process);
            info('Editor opened successfully.');
        } else {
            info('Failed to open editor.');
        }

This was working smoothly for local/HTTP in IIS but it seems that HTTPS have some configuration for running exec command?
What I've done so far:

Tried using the Process Package and exec() but still encountering the same error.
Check the configuration in php.ini to confirm that popen is not disabled

This was working smoothly for local/HTTP in IIS but it seems that HTTPS have some configuration for running exec command or is the popen being blocked? Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you!

since you know it is related to switching to https, did you check the network trafic and if any of your website ressources is being denied load because it still use http protocol

I checked it under development tools and none of it is being blocked. Also, it was able to call the api for opening the editor and the logs are returning successful response.

Do you get a message of Failed to open editor.? Did you get an exception? I understand the editor is not loading, but how exactly is this manifesting? Did you look into the server logs (not in the Dev Tools of the browser) for errors? If so, did you find an error message with a stack trace?

@LajosArpad I'm checking error logs from the server as well, and the response of the popen returns 'Editor opened successfully'. I'm not really sure what is blocking the editor to open.

https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 due to session isolation you shouldn’t ever see the editor. So I can only assume you missed some details when writing this question. Besides, PHP on IIS/Windows lost important support from Microsoft, so you should think twice if you should migrate away, https://docs.lextudio.com/phpmanager/getting-started/supported-platforms.html

The editor is started on the server, not the client.

What are the detailed error response code and error message? Have you tried using FRT to get the logs to locate the issue?
